# Calculate the % of duplicates in a dataframe based on specific combinations

Tags: python, pandas, combinations, python-itertools

I have this df :

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data = {'ID_Client': [12,13,11,14,32,48,21,8],
                 'Name': ['Bryan','John','Sonya','Mark','Mark','Bryan','John','Emma'],
                 'Birth_date': ['10-06-2001','12-08-1991','14-06-1976','15-06-1962','15-06-1962','10-06-2001','12-08-1991','14-06-1976'],
                 'Email':['bryan@gmail.com','john@hotmail.com','','','','not-bryan@gmail.com','john@hotmail.com','emma@gmail.com'],
                 'SMS':['','0718181818','0611111111','0688888888','0688888888','','0718181818','']})
```

Thanks to combinations, I found a way to report the % of duplicates based on all combinations possible, like this :

```
from itertools import combinations

tab=[]

for a,b,c,d,e in combinations(range(0, len(df.columns)), 5):
     for i in range(1, len(df.columns)+1):

           tab.append([t for t in combinations(df.columns, i)])

tab2=[[] for i in range(len(df.columns)**len(df.columns))] #could be better I know, but at least it works
number=0

for i in range(len(tab)):
     for j in range(len(tab[i])):
           data_f=df.dropna(subset=tab[i][j]).loc[df.duplicated(subset=tab[i][j],keep=False)]
           tab2[number][i:0]=[tab[i][j]]
           tab2[number][len(df.columns):0] = [len(data_f)/len(df)]
           number+=1

           print(tab[i][j])
print(tab2)

tab2 = pd.DataFrame(tab2)
tab2.iloc[:, 1]
tab2[2]=tab2[0]
tab2 = tab2.iloc[: , 1:]
tab2
```

The output is something like this :

[image]

etc...

**Now** I would like to do the same, but in the 2nd column I would prefer something like this :

[image]

So for example, if I take the 6th row of this last image, I would like to know what is the % of duplicates when 2 clients have same id, same name, same birth, a different email (not null), and a NULL SMS value for one of the clients.

Can someone help me please? Is it even possible to do that?

Thanks in advance, take care of you !

Comment: Should not the duplicated in your dataframe have the *same* `ID_Client`?

Comment: not necessarily. That's why I'm trying to find same client (same name, birth date, etc...) to join them and give them the same ID, to clean the table